# MVC: best way to display data from 2 tables in 1 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I'm trying to make a view that has data from 2 tables in my database. I have looked up a couple things and I tried to use a ViewModel but I can't get it to work. Then I was thinking about using a view and a partial view to display data from the 2 tables. What is the best way using the ViewModel or using a view and a partial view?

Also if someone knows what I am doing wrong with my ViewModel and wants to help that would be awesome.

my 2 models:

```
public partial class prospect
{
    public prospect()
    {
        this.result = new HashSet<result>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public int testid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string cellnumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime timestampstart { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> timestampend { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> totalresult { get; set; }
    public string birthdate { get; set; }
    public string school { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> grade { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string cityandcode { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<result> result { get; set; }
    public virtual resultpersection resultpersection { get; set; }
}

public partial class resultpersection
   {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int prospectid { get; set; }
    public int sectionid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> result { get; set; }

    public virtual prospect prospect { get; set; }
    public virtual section section { get; set; }
}
```

The things I want to display are:
prospect.name , prospect.surname, prospect.totalresult and  all the results per section of this prospect(this comes from the resultpersection table)

my viewmodel:

```
namespace testAptitude.Models
{
  public class ResultsPerProspect
  {

    public List<prospect> prospect { get; set; }
    public List<resultpersection> resultPerSection { get; set; }
 }
}
```

my controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ResultsPerProspect vm = new ResultsPerProspect();
        vm.prospect = (from p in db.prospect select p).ToList();
        vm.resultPerSection = (from rps in db.resultpersection select rps).ToList(); ;
        List<ResultsPerProspect> viewModelList = new List<ResultsPerProspect>();

        viewModelList.Add(vm);


        return View(viewModelList.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

my view

```
 @model IEnumerable<testAptitude.Models.ResultsPerProspect>

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.prospect)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.prospect)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can't do item.prospect.name because it say's that is doesn't contain a definition for name

and what is dispalys now is this:

prospect

System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[testAptitude.Models.result]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code you can access it using

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().prospect)
```

You are passing `IEnumerable<testAptitude.Models.ResultsPerProspect>` to your view i.e multiple objects of class `ResultsPerProspect`. You would need to iterate throught this List. Each items in this list will contain definition for `prospect` and `resultPerSection`.

Or you can pass single object of class `ResultsPerProspect` as you are just adding single element in list.

**UPDATE**
You have List Of ResultsPerProspect. and each item of ResultsPerProspect has List of `prospect` and List of `resultPerSection`. So you would need to first iterate for loop over List Of ResultsPerProspect. and inside that for loop , for loop for List of `prospect` List of and `resultPerSection`

CODE

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

    foreach (var pros in item.prospect)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => pros.Name)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? I iterate the list already by the foreach? can you give a code example please?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class ("Container") that consists of your two (sub)classes (let's say A and B)? You can then create a Container object and put the needed objects in Container.A and Container.B. You can then easly pass "Container" to your view and access your objects.

Comment: Isn't that what viewModels is? a new class where you put in the two seperate classes? I never used a ViewModel before so I'm not sure?